# Is the producers' choice of language off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

If someone asks why a film was produced in English instead of Japanese (for example only), is that considered "behind the scenes" or is it off topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why it should be off topic, it seems to fit firmly in the behind the scenes area. As long as the work is SFF-nal you shouldn't have a problem.

That said these types of questions don't seem like they would be particularly interesting as I imagine 99% of the time the answer would be "because it was for an English speaking audience not a Japanese one" or "because the cast was English" to use your example. So, I'd expect the question would get some downvotes *unless* you could explain *why* it would have made more sense to produce it in Japanese.

Comment: My immediate thought was "It's one of those terrible movies adapted from an anime." In which case "Why not Japanese?" is more succinctly answered with "They just didn't care."